# Guinan suggests Geordi drink milk despite Human lactose intolerance - how come?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In Star Trek TNG, Season 3 Episode 21 ("Hollow Pursuits"), Guinan suggests that Lt. Commander LaForge try drinking warm milk because it "helps you sleep". However, from what I've [read](http://news.cornell.edu/stories/2005/06/lactose-intolerance-linked-ancestral-struggles-climate-diseases), most adult Humans are lactose-intolerant, and 75% of African Americans. And - perhaps a bit surprisingly for people like me of European descent - "common symptoms include nausea, cramps, bloating, gas and diarrhea that begin about 30 minutes to two hours after eating or drinking foods containing the milk sugar lactose."

So in-universe, LaForge is likely intolerant and this is even more likely given his African descent. Now, true, Guinan isn't Human, but wouldn't she at least know most Humans are intolerant? Why would she suggest milk to him, then?

More significantly - out-of-universe, actors Burton and Goldberg are African-American, and likely have many friends/family members who are lactose-intolerant. Wouldn't they have suggested a change of this line of the script?

I live in a country with a very small percentage of people of African descent so I don't really have an idea about milk-consumption patterns; maybe it's not uncommon for African-Americans to drink milk despite the intolerance?

Comment: It's the 24th century. They can probably give you something that will break down the lactose. This is a culture that has synthohol. http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Synthehol an alcohol that you can choose to sober up from. They definitely have milk you can drink even if you're lactose intolerant.

Comment: Guinan isn't human, she's El-Aurian.

Comment: @Valorum: I did say that. But her Human bar patrons should be mostly lactose-intolerant.

Comment: It's also worth noting that lactose intolerance isn't an on/off condition. It's a very big sliding scale. It can be something you have for a long time and aren't even aware of.

Comment: also, the episode was shot 1989/1990. Lactose intollerance research has come a BIG way in the 28 years since.

Comment: @Trish: I don't think African Americans needed scientific research to know that milk is problematic for Black people.

Comment: @einpoklum until the mid 1990s lactose intollerance was very poorly understood in many regards. links to regional groups only have been researched in the early 2000s properly.

Comment: @Trish: Understanding the mechanism is irrelevant, people were "milk-intolerant" then rather than "lactose-intolerant"; same difference.

Comment: There's no evidence that Geordi himself is lactose intolerant, regardless of his ethnicity. Not worth a downvote imo but this question is silly.

Comment: As for whether lactose intolerant people sometimes drink milk or consume other dairy products anyway, yes, absolutely. As Jontoa said, this isn't like a food allergy. According to the NICHHD: "Individuals vary in their degree of lactose intolerance, but even children and teenagers with primary lactose intolerance can usually consume 8 to 12 ounces (1 to 1.5 cups) of milk without experiencing symptoms." And that's not even considering people who consume more than that intentionally.

Comment: I don't think there's much reason to downvote this question. Sure, it does proceed from an incorrect premise, but it's a valuable angle, and one that's infrequently considered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have specific knowledge of the scriptwriting process for that episode. That said, here's a few very plausible explanations, in-universe and out.

- **Geordi is naturally lactose tolerant, and Guinan knows this.** 
  You say that 75% of African-Americans are lactose-intolerant. Actually, researchers have usually estimated more like 80-90%. However, this still leaves 10-20% who aren't, into which group Geordi could easily fall. In other words, it's an uncommon trait, but not unheard of.
- **Geordi is naturally lactose-intolerant, but consumes some dairy anyway** (and Guinan knows this). Lactose tolerance is a spectrum, as mentioned by Jontia in the comments. It is very possible for a lactose-intolerant person to consume small amounts of dairy with little to no ill effect. 
  Consider, for instance, [this statement](https://www1.nichd.nih.gov/publications/pubs/Documents/NICHD_MM_HC_FS_rev.pdf) by the NICHD:

  > Individuals vary in their degree of lactose intolerance, but even
  >   children and teenagers with primary lactose intolerance can usually
  >   consume 8 to 12 ounces (1 to 1.5 cups) of milk without experiencing
  >   symptoms."

  It should be no surprise that this is the case. Although African-Americans are much less likely to be lactose tolerant than European-Americans, and although this has likely contributed to the subject receiving less attention, it is not common in other groups. [Some researchers](https://winnersdrinkmilk.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/NMA_LI_Statement_2009.pdf) have estimated similar lactose intolerance rates in Jewish Americans and Asian Americans. (Interestingly, the group with the highest rates of lactose intolerance is Native Americans, with rates close to 100%). But even European Americans have been estimated to be more likely to be somewhat lactose intolerant than not (52%, possibly).

  Selling dairy products in the numbers they're sold today in the United States and perhaps elsewhere would be virtually impossible if no one with a degree of lactose intolerance could consume them. 
  **Indeed, members of all these groups can and do consume milk and dairy, with varying health consequences.**
- **Geordi is lactose intolerant and consumes a substitute** (which Guinan calls milk).

  This has basically been covered in other answers. Either she means milk with lactase, or a plant-based milk, or something futuristic.
- **Geordi is not naturally lactose tolerant, but uses some drug or modification to consume dairy, because he likes it** (and Guinan knows this).

  We are talking about Star Trek here. Whether someone likes the taste of milk, engine oil, or hydrochloric acid, they can probably eat it if they really want to.

As to why neither of the actors objected, I can only speculate, but the in-universe reasons mostly work out of universe as well. Goldburg and Burton would be well aware that there are some African-Americans with high degrees of lactose tolerance. Though, at that time, they might not have conceptualized it as such, they'd probably have known black people who could eat a lot of dairy.

Similarly, they'd certainly have known plenty of people who could eat *some* dairy without getting sick. In point of fact, they probably ate some themselves, like the [overwhelming majority](https://www.ars.usda.gov/ARSUserFiles/80400530/pdf/DBrief/3_milk_consumption_0506.pdf) of both African and European Americans (note that the daily consumption of milk for black Americans was still 1/3 of a cup, non-negligible).

In point of fact, either Burton, Goldberg, or both could easily have fallen into either the first or second category.

Or it just didn't matter much to them.

Answer (score 9):

Today, lactose-free milk is widely available to consumers (at least in California where *Star Trek* was produced).*  The most straightforward way to make it is to add [lactase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lactase) to regular milk, but there are numerous [plant milks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plant_milk) which are also naturally lactose-free.  Even if we assume that a treatment and cure for lactose intolerance would not be developed by the 24th century, it is inconceivable that the replicators would be unable to produce such milks on demand given that we have them now.

In short: This is mostly a solved problem, and will not become an unsolved problem in the 24th century.

* Source: I live in California, and I have occasionally accidentally purchased lactose-free milk instead of regular milk.  It should also be noted that, as Trish points out in another answer, this was *much less true* around the time this episode was produced.  But regardless, they will have these milks in the 24th century.

Comment: how was lactose free milk availability in 1989/1990, when the episode was shot?

Comment: @Trish: Soy and almond milks are [ancient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soy_milk#History), but I'm having trouble finding good dates for lactase-treated milk.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that plant "milks" are a bit vegetable "burgers" (or Star Trek "synthehol") in which the primary concern historically has been making it taste like the original food rather than duplicating it's nutritional content. But yes, I agree that this ought to be a solved problem by then.

Comment: But isn't lactose-free milk like caffeine-free coffee? i.e. having none of the effect? Specifically, would lactose-free milk "help you sleep" the way regular milk does?

Comment: @einpoklum: I've never heard that.  Lactase-treated milk is nutritionally almost the same thing as regular milk, including overall fat, sugar, and protein content.  It seems implausible that breaking the lactose apart into galactose and glucose would completely alter its character in this fashion.

Comment: Lactose-free milk was only invented 2001 for the note.

Comment: @Trish: That's fine, this is an in-universe answer.

Answer (score 3):

First, let's face it: this episode is currently out for over 28 years, as it was aired in april 1990. That means, the research it can reflect at best is 1989.

Now, serching for lactose intollerance, I found that in 1990, "progress is being made in the basic understanding of the molecular and cellular biology of this enzyme [lactase]"<sup>[1](https://www.annualreviews.org/doi/abs/10.1146/annurev.me.41.020190.001041?journalCode=med)</sup> and " there have been a few interesting clinical advances in our knowledge of the digestion of lactose."<sup>[2](http://pediatrics.aappublications.org/content/86/4/643)</sup>. The Abstracts though mainly describe how to diagnose lactose intollerance, not how to treat or cure it.

Lactose free milk was only made 11 years later: the process to get it was patented in 2001<sup>[3](https://patents.google.com/patent/US6881428B2/en)</sup>.

According to a map, only about 15% of the US population are lactose intolletrant without knowing skin color, but that is significantly less than the percentage of african americans.<sup>[4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lactose_intolerance#/media/File:Worldwide_prevalence_of_lactose_intolerance_in_recent_populations.jpg)</sup>

I conclude, that I find it  is highly likely that

1. The makers of the episode didn't knew about lactose intollerance at all, even as it has been found out about in 1978.
2. Neither Burton nor Goldberg knew about lactose intollerance being something that might be linked to them being African American.

Since nobody knew about it when the episode was shot, nobody cared about it. Only the research of the late 1990s and 2000s established that African American heritage might increase the chance for lactose intollerance.

### tl;dr

It was likely not known at the set in 1989 how widespread lactose intollerance among people of african anchestors was at the time when the episode was made.

Comment: When 75% of an ethnic group are lactose intolerant, they don't need any "research" to know that.

Comment: @einpoklum - Prooooobably. But it's surprisingly easy for people not to understand their own bodies. For example, misconceptions about miscarriage (while more common among men than women) have been found to be prevalent among women, and even held by many women who have themselves miscarried.

Comment: And [here](https://www.livescience.com/42854-women-hold-misconceptions-reproduction.html) is a list of many misconceptions that many women (and, one presumes, even more men) have about female reproductive health, including some that they might have been able to observe themselves. So while you're probably right, I don't think we can simply take that fact as a given.

Comment: Since I haven't done any research on lactose tolerance attitudes in the 90s, I don't want to speculate too much, but in light of the fact that people without lactose tolerance can still often consume small amounts of dairy without discomfort, this would offer a plausible explanation for even a lactose intolerant person not knowing that they're "lactose intolerant." They might think that everyone can only have small amounts of dairy (and in their  country or social circle, that might be mostly true).

Answer (score 3):

Who said Geordi La Forge is African-*American*?

He was born in Mogadishu. East Africa is home of one of the recent clusters (in the last few thousand years) of mutations that allow for adult lactose tolerance, so if his family had members from that side of the continent, it's entirely reasonable he could have inherited lactose tolerance.

The majority of black African-Americans, at least not recent immigrants, are descended from people from *West* Africa.

Comment: Ah, a good point. I am not a Star Trek expert, so I missed that.

Comment: Nobody said Geordi LaForge is African-American, I said the actor was.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the difficulty Troi had in getting real chocolate, the synthesized milk available (it’s a starship sans cattle typically, milk only keeps so long) is likely tailored to the person, since their medical records would be accessible to the computer.

Comment: I don't think that would be the case, but +1 for the novel idea.